# Using MSMQ on Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10

Tags: raspberry-pi, msmq, visual-studio-2015, azureservicebus, windows-10

I want to create an application that runs on Raspberry Pi 2 and send messages with some collected data using MSMQ. I have installed Windows 10 on my Raspberry Pi.

I have created a test project (Windows Universal type) for this purpose using MS Visual Studio 2015. Also I can't use a lot of references (for example System.Messaging), because of the Raspberry architecture reasons as I understand.

Is it even possible to use MSMQ on Raspberry Pi 2? Or help me please to find any  analogs of MSMQ to send messages from Raspberry Pi.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 IoT Core is meant for IoT scenarios, which means that you'll ultimately have to connect to the cloud. The best approach here would be to connect your Windows 10 Universal App on the Raspberry Pi 2 the Azure using Service Bus Queues. This MSDN mag article explains the approach: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574801.aspx.

In terms of implementation, the Service Bus docs for Azure are at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/service-bus/. Queues are covered at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/. the Azure SDK will be available to your app on the Pi.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will investigate this approach.

Comment: Also note that while service bus queues are the closest thing to having MSMQ on the raspberry pi with Windows 10 IoT Core, you should also consider Azure Event Hubs since they are specifically designed for massive injestion of data from thousands of IoT devices. See docs at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-hubs/. A full working IoT sample was designed by MSOpenTech and its called Connect the Dots, see https://github.com/msopentech/connectthedots. Two Windows 10 sample IoT clients are at https://github.com/MSOpenTech/connectthedots/tree/master/Devices/DirectlyConnectedDevices.